# The `wrapfigure` environment breaks when put inside another environment

Tags: environments, wrapfigure

I've tried using the `wrapfigure` environment (from the `wrapfig`) package, but it acts in such a way that I can't use it.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig,mwe}

\newenvironment{testenv}{%
  \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.5\linewidth}%
    \vspace{.5\baselineskip}%
  }{%
  \end{wrapfigure}}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.5\textwidth}\vspace{.5\baselineskip}
  This is some dummy text.  This is some dummy text.
  This is some dummy text.  This is some dummy text.
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{testenv}
  This is some dummy text.  This is some dummy text.
  This is some dummy text.  This is some dummy text.
\end{testenv}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

This produces the output below.
What causes this error, and is there any way to fix it?

[image]

---

While a fix for `wrapfigure` would be cool, if a simpler fix exists for my specific use case, I'd be grateful to have a peek at it `:)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the command-form of the `wrapfigure` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{wrapfig,lipsum}

\newenvironment{testenv}{%
  \wrapfigure{r}{.5\linewidth}%
    \vspace{.5\baselineskip}%
  }{%
  \endwrapfigure}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.5\textwidth}\vspace{.5\baselineskip}
  This is some dummy text.  This is some dummy text.
  This is some dummy text.  This is some dummy text.
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{testenv}
  This is some dummy text.  This is some dummy text.
  This is some dummy text.  This is some dummy text.
\end{testenv}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does the original issue then revolve around grouping? I don't know terribly much about `\begin` and `\end`, but I do know they they begin and end groups as well.

Comment: @SeanAllred: This *is* related to grouping, yes, and using the command-form circumvents that. From the [`wrapfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/wrapfig-doc.pdf) (p 1): "Some idiosyncrasies:... If you put a `wrapfigure` in a `\parbox` or a `minipage`, or any other type of grouping, the text wrapping should end before the group does." In this case, it does not (`\end{testenv}` occurs *before* the text wrapping).

Comment: I read that part of the documentation, but I thought it had meant something along the lines of 'you must end the content the `wrapfigure` wraps before you end the group'. What exactly then does it mean by '*text wrapping*'?

Comment: @SeanAllred: I read it that "text wrapping" refers to the text being wrapped. So your group `testenv` ended even before the text-to-be-wrapped was found. I think there is some `\aftergroup` usages in [`wrapfig.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/wrapfig.sty) that could imply this requirement.